# Selenium - Check character inside a variable

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a field that stores numbers. And this field, when it reaches more than one thousand, it automatically inserts a comma, example:

- 998
- 999
- 1,000

I store the value of this field in a variable, like this:

```
storeValue | id=field | variableName
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to validate the variable and, if it has the comma, remove it.

Example workflow:

- Stores the field value in a variable.
- Check if this variable contains a comma in it.
- if YES (e.g: 1,000), then remove the comma and just let 1000 stored.
- if NO, let it the way it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute javascript, call `replace()` accessing `variableName` through `storedVars`:

```
store | javascript{storedVars['variableName'].replace(',','')} | variableName
```

Comment: Same error :-( --> [info] Executing: |storeValue | javascript{storedVars['quantity'].replace(',','')} | quantity |
[error] Element 1000 not found

Comment: @user2576376 how about now? Using `store` instead of `storeValue`.

Comment: Oh Yeah! Now it works with the STORE command, thanks a lot! =D